# Wrong time calculation in the list of ranks

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation league says I've been a member for 1 year, 12 months](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81415/reputation-league-says-ive-been-a-member-for-1-year-12-months)

My entries in the ranking list shows "member since 1 year, 12 month" - I'd expect that 12 month makes a year :-)

I think it may be because today is the start of the month, where I will have the 2nd birthday of my membership.

[image]

Comment: Probably 11 months would be correct?

Comment: Yes (as of today) I think the 2nd anniversary is in the next few days.